# The best approach to display a long profile information

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-behavior, design-patterns

I was re-designing a desktop application and the target audiences are mostly eldery women (user average age is around 50 years old). This application keeps the data of church and medical members so it contains of data tables, long forms, and long informations. Currently, I'm stuck with the design for showing the information when user clicks the profile.

As you can see, the profile information is too long and I would like to keep it neat but still have a nice look and a good user experience, considering that the audiences are eldery women. Another problem is even the data that they don't fill in on the form must be shown too and it's causing many empty spaces there.

Can you suggest the alternatives for the design and what's the best approach to display a long information for these target audiences ?
Thank you !

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## **Group Related Information**

Users think in batches, and long forms can feel overwhelming. By creating logical groups the user will make sense of the form much faster.

Also, show some visual feedback after completing each group. A sense of accomplishment to keep users engaged.

---

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks it's helpful ! But, any other design suggestions to simplify the form or what should do with the empty space to make it efficient ? Another question, when you scroll down the form that I've made you will see the empty space too on left and right side, while the position of information itself is center, do you think it has a good user experience ? Personally, I'm distracted by the empty space. If you have any feedbacks regarding to the design I would really appreciate it. Thank you in advance ! @DPS

Comment: @Livin think of using Accordion control - it helps in your situation. Demo http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Accordion-Slider-Style-jQuery-Form-Wizard-Plugin-Formalize/

Answer (score 0):

1. Utilize your current sub-navigation tabs. Although the first tab may be
   titled, "Biodata" make the next tab "Contact" (for example). This way, you can cut 1/2 of your form and paste it into "Contact" (like the phone, email, address, etc)
2. Another idea is not allow a 2-column design for some fields that do
   not require lengthy answers. For example, gender can share a line
   with name title (F, Dr). But be careful with this approach because mobile devices can only see 400px width.